# FullCalendar, JSON array empty but working on PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, json, fullcalendar

I am configuring FullCalendar with a MySQL DB, using PHP to process and return a JSON.

- **db-connect.php** - fetches results from my Db and encodes to JSON.
- **get-events.php** - reads JSON, converts to FullCalendar
- **json.html** - is my front-end calendar view

File contents below, but before reading: `db-connect.php` successfully outputs JSON that I have verified on JSONLint.

```
[{"title":"Test new calendar","start":"2015-07-21","end":"2015-07-22"}]
```

`get-events.php` is successfully 'reading' `db-connect.php` as the "php/get-events.php must be running." error message on my front-end view has disappeared (shows if for example it can't establish that `db-connect.php` is in the directory, or spelling error in file name, etc).

However when I either pass the query via `params` or check in Firebug console, the JSON array is empty.

```
/cal/demos/php/get-events.php?start=2015-07-01&end=2015-07-31
```

returns `[]` whereas my test calendar entry does fall within these parameters.

I'm convinced it's my `db-connect.php` that is the error, but I'm scratching my head about it. Relative newbie so I'm sure it's obvious!

**db-connect.php**

```
<?php
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","");
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("test",$db);

    $result = mysql_query("select * from cal", $db);  

    $json_response = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];
        $row_array['start'] = $row['start'];
        $row_array['end'] = $row['end'];

        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
    }
    echo json_encode($json_response);

    mysql_close($db);
 ?>
```

**get-events.php**

```
<?php



// Require our Event class and datetime utilities
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/utils.php';


if (!isset($_GET['start']) || !isset($_GET['end'])) {
    die("Please provide a date range.");
}


$range_start = parseDateTime($_GET['start']);
$range_end = parseDateTime($_GET['end']);


$timezone = null;
if (isset($_GET['timezone'])) {
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone($_GET['timezone']);
}

$json = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/db-connect.php');
$input_arrays = json_decode($json, true);

$output_arrays = array();

if (is_array($input_arrays) || is_object($input_arrays))
{
foreach ($input_arrays as $array) {

    $event = new Event($array, $timezone);

    if ($event->isWithinDayRange($range_start, $range_end)) {
        $output_arrays[] = $event->toArray();
    }
}
}

echo json_encode($output_arrays);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents`doesn't parse the php file. It will output the programmcode in this case. Add this function to your get-events.php

```
function loadPhpFile($file) {
    ob_start(); 
    include $file;
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
```

And then replace

```
$json = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/db-connect.php');
```

with

```
$json = loadPhpFile(dirname(__FILE__) . '/db-connect.php');
```

And as a hint: Please use objects (OOP) and mysqli. [PHP Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

Comment: I know I'm not meant to say 'thanks', but for future reference for other users - this worked perfectly! Thanks for the help! (my rep isn't high enough to +1 you)